# Finding unit vector with given vector and an angle between the two vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Question: 
Let w = <1,1,1>. Find a unit vector v such that the angle between v and w is π/4.

My calculation:
let v =

cos(pi/4) = sqrt(2)/2

sqrt(2)/2 = (a(1)+b(1)+c(1))/(sqrt(1^2 +1^2+1^2)*sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2))

let a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1

=> sqrt(2)/2 = (a+b+c) / sqrt(3)

=> sqrt(2)*sqrt(3) / 2 = a + b + c

and from here I am stuck..

From my class right now (intro to lin arg), class covered projection last friday meaning we did not cover rotation.. etc.

Please help! 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The unit vectors making an angle of $\frac{\pi}{4}$ about the vector $\mathbf{w}=\langle 1,1,1\rangle$ will lie in a cone with center axis containing the origin and having direction $\mathbf{w}$. So one of them will lie directly "underneath" $\mathbf{w}$ in the sense that it will have coordinates of the form

$$ \mathbf{v}=\langle a,a,c\rangle $$

In other words, there will be a solution where $b=a$ in your approach.

Then you get two non-linear equations in two variables.

1. $2a+c=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{2}$
2. $2a^2+c^2=1$

Graphed in the "$ac$-plane" these will be a straight line and an ellipse with possibly two solutions.

From the first equation set $c=\dfrac{\sqrt{6}}{2}-2a$ and substitute the value of $c^2$ into the second equation. This gives a somewhat messy quadratic equation in $a$, but it can be solved.

Select the appropriate solution for $a$ and find the corresponding value for $c$ and you will have a correct answer. Expect the answer to contain a square root or two.

**ADDENDUM:** Should you wish to continue your chosen approach to the problem and use my advice on how to continue down that path one of the solutions you obtain should be

$$ \mathbf{v}=\left\langle\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3}}{6},\frac{\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{3}}{6},\frac{\sqrt{6}-2\sqrt{3}}{6} \right\rangle$$